# MYSQL #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm having trouble using a regular expression to select some results from my MySQL table.
I'm using this query

```
select t.City, t.Mall, t.Number_Phone,  t.Number_Phone rlike '^((\+380){1}(\(542\)){1}[0-9]{6}){1}&' as test from (select c.name as City, m.name as Mall, p.text_value as Number_Phone from objects c cross join objects m left join params p on (m.object_id=p.object_id and p.attr_id=11) where (c.object_type_id=23 and m.object_type_id=25)) as t
```

And it says

```
#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

Regular exp:

```
'^((\+380){1}(\(542\)){1}[0-9]{6}){1}&'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to escape the `+` twice:

```
'^((\\+380){1}(\(542\)){1}[0-9]{6}){1}&'
```